# How to create drupal Batch Operation on Custom Form

Tags: drupal-7

I am learing batch operations api. i have tried to create a batch operation using a form here is my hook_form

```
function batch_form_get_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form = array();

  $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Select',
    '#type' =>'select',
    '#options' => array(
      'batch1' => 'Batch 1',
      'batch2' => 'Batch 2',
    ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit'
  );
  return $form;
}
```

here is my form submit function

```
function batch_form_get_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
  $function = 'batch_process_form';
  $_SESSION['http_request_count'] =0;
  $batch = $function;
  batch_set($batch);
  dsm ($function);
}
```

here is my batch process function which i used on batch_set function

```
function batch_process_form(){
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  $operations[] = array('batch_operation_result',array($i));
}
  $title = "Batch Started";
  $init_message = "Initialing Batch";
  $progress_message = "Work in Progress";

  $batch = array(
    'operations' => $operations,
    'title' => $title,
    'init_message' => $init_message,
    'progress_message' => $progress_message,
  );
  return $batch;
}
```

when i tried to run the batch i got the following error

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/dina/static/d7/includes/form.inc on line 4396
```

on the line no 4396 of form.inc

```
  $batch_set = $init + $batch_definition + $defaults;
```

i don't no what i am missing

Comment: What it the $defaults variable? I think you have to set it for the #select type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed one thing.

In your submit function, instead of

$batch = $function;

try

$batch = $function();

Good luck